# What is the best iterating method for, say, MERGE, for a memory optimized SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures, memory-optimized-tables

I have to work with sets with millions of rows in my SQL Server database.

Almost all my commands use the `MERGE` statement. I merge here and there, this table and that table. I use stored procedures for that as I believe that would provide the best performance.

I found out that the process is too slow for me (merging 2kk rows - seemingly random from 5 to 50 seconds), that is, the performance is not as it would seem the best, and for some reason I couldn't find the reason: I opened the Task Manager and Resource Monitor, initiated some heavy `MERGE` queries, ensured that no scans or other unpleasant items are present in the actual execution plan. And I saw very low CPU, memory, and disk drive consumption. The reason for this is still not known to me.

Lately I also found out that memory optimized tables coupled with native stored procedures are supposed to provide better performance.

It turns out that `Merge` isn't available for MO-tables, and MO-tables aren't available for native stored procedures.

The [only example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/implementing-merge-functionality-in-a-natively-compiled-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017) of substituting Merge on MSDN uses weird approach, based on while loop and an extra column RowId to "access a row by index". Well, I learned some more info, I repeated the MSDN example, established some hash index with lots of buckets (8kk) on that column and indeed, there was some performance gain.

But again, each iteration in the loop requires at least two index seeks, as well as insert/update/delete when the conditions are met.

So I ask: is there any useful strategies for placing a really performant `merge`? Is there any way to, I don't know, may be writing a CLR procedure? Would that be better? Any other tips or hints?

Comment: Strongly recommend balancing [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) against your enthusiasm for `MERGE`...

Comment: @AaronBertrand How is this relevant? The question is how to implement merge's behaviour (in MO SP).

Comment: Why do people say "I have to work with millions of rows" like that's a big deal? SQL is designed for that.

Comment: @Ashigore it is, but for some reason the SQL server doesn't really load the PC up executing my commands. And hence I'm asking how to improve the performance.

Comment: I suggest first try splitting into separate `UPDATE` / `INSERT` statements and taking the time to optimise that that before going down the memory optimised tables route. If your logic uses a lot of T-SQL, you'll need to refactor it all for memory optimised tables. SQL CLR is not a performance improvement solution for set based operations.

Comment: Memory optimised does not support `UPDATE FROM` so it would appear that the only merge possible in a row based fashion is to delete then insert all records based on primary key. Alternatively, perhaps memory optimised is so fast that it's one situation where cursor based update is quick enough

Comment: You said: "Almost all my commands use the MERGE statement." It wasn't clear in your question that you're converting every single table to memory-optimized, or that every system where you do this is under any kind of memory-optimized consideration, so I thought I would share that `MERGE` has other problems than what you have seen, and you should be nervous about it in other scenarios, too. **Comments are not answers.** If that link was trying to *solve your problem,* it would have been written up as an answer. Take advice as if you came asking for help.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The cursors are unavailable in native procs, the SSMS told me when i tried to build yet another stored procedure. AaronBertrand, okay sorry then. I do merge a lot, but I only converted 1 or 2 tables to memory optimized, since even they are causing so much trouble with their limitations. I'm just starting to think that simply downloading all data from SQL and using C# to implement the logic would be the fastest to write AND to process.

Comment: By cursor I mean any row based iteration like a while loop. Writing something in C# is using completely the wrong hammer. As is converting to memory optimised. Again I suggest you split your merge into INSERT / UPDATE and take the time to optimise them individually. For something that takes 50 seconds I suggest you use `sp_whoisactive` and observe the waits. You might find using insert/update instead of merge solves your problem anyway

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid there is also a `DELETE` for `NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`, which is the main reason for MERGing. Thx for the `sp_whoisactive ` tho, i'll look into that.

Comment: The `DELETE` might be most of the reason for the performance issue. So split it into three (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) and see if that's faster. If not, work out which of the three is the problem.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid lol, I just checked, the same algorithm takes 110 ms (for 1mil records) to merge using simple C#. I seriously doubt the MSSQL's abilities now. I used a simple MERGE. Why is it so slow? Even in native procs... [I don't understand](https://snag.gy/fLhPoZ.jpg). The sql code also takes **[100 lines of code](https://pastebin.com/Wp3tujWf)** to do two `while`-based iterators and repeat practically the same simple logic.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but your code (the first code I've seen so far) only deletes from an in memory int array and doesn't write back to the database? It's not really doing the same thing. I suggest you convert your MERGE to a single DELETE and see how fast it is. That's my advice.